# Inner Product of a function and cosh

Tags: inner-products

This is the question, but I don't have a clue to solve the second part.

Prove that in $W[0, 1]$ 
$$<f, \cosh > = f(1)  \sinh 1 $$
and deduce that

$$ \{f \in W[0; 1] | \, f(1) = 0\} $$
is a closed subspace of $W[0, 1]$.

And, the inner product is: 
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)g(t)+ \acute{f}(t)\acute{g}(t) dt$$

Anyone, got any idea?

Comment: What is your definition of inner product? There are a lot of them.

Comment: Why is hyperbolic-geometry tagged??

Comment: @martycohen Thanks, I've correct it.

Comment: Another question: What does $\acute{f}(t)\acute{g}(t)$ mean? Derivative? If so, it should be $f'(t)g'(t)$.

Comment: @martycohen yes it is derivative. I didn't know what is the symbol for that in latex.

Comment: Just a regular single quote. Second derivative is to single quotes. And so on.

Comment: Thanks @martycohen

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start.

If
$\langle f,g \rangle 
= \int_{a}^{b} (f(t)g(t)+ f'(t)g'(t)) dt
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\langle f,\cosh \rangle 
&= \int_{a}^{b} (f(t)\cosh(t)+ f'(t)\cosh'(t)) dt\\
&= \int_{a}^{b} (f(t)\cosh(t)+ f'(t)\sinh(t)) dt\\
&= \frac12\int_{a}^{b} (f(t)(e^t+e^{-t})+ f'(t)(e^t-e^{-t})) dt
\qquad\text{(don't know if you need these lines)}\\
&= \frac12\left(\int_{a}^{b} e^t(f(t)+f'(t)) dt+\int_{a}^{b} e^{-t}(f(t)-f'(t)) dt\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: That's correct, but you don't need to change sinh and cosh to exponential, if you just use partial integration, you will have the answer. But my problem mostly is the second part. it says to deduce that ${f∈W[0;1]|f(1)=0}$ is a closed subset of W[0,1]. I don't know this part.